# Server requesting image every time

Tags: javascript, image, iis, preloading

i´m getting some strange behaviour when i deployed my web app on windows server with Microsoft IIS.

creating an image object

```
 img = new Image() ; 
 img.src = 'someimg.png' ;
 img.addEventListener('load', incrementImageCount ) ;
```

I´m doing image preloading via javascript and locally it works perfect, but when i deploy on the server the browser request an image every time it´s draw or redraw. So i have some awful looks while it´s loading. So in resources on web inspector i see the same images, multiple times.

Any ideas why this may be happening?

Comment: You should use a tool like "Tamper Data" for Firefox to examine the HTTP headers the server is sending with the image.

Comment: Also, it's not the **server** that's requesting the image, it's the **client**.

Comment: the server is probably responding with headers preventing the client from cacheing

Comment: this are the response headers
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Access-control-allow-headers:*
Access-control-allow-methods:PUT, GET,POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Content-Length:18266
Content-Type:image/png
Date:Thu, 11 Jul 2013 04:08:36 GMT
ETag:W/"0f1308507ece1:0"
Last-Modified:Thu, 11 Jul 2013 06:33:14 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET

Comment: yes i forgot a colon when i deploy on the server, the browser(client) request an image

Comment: any idea where the problem is on that?